# Elegant way of downloading images to iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, mobile

PHP5.2.x  back end.  The text data transfer is using JSON objects.

Am looking at how best to transfer around 10, 30kB PNG images from the server to the iPhone client.

Have looked at Base64 encoding the images on the server and using JSON to transport.  However this does come with a 30% overhead in increased filesize.

Perhaps a simple http GET of each image from the client would be best?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PNGs are already compressed, you're probably not going to gain anything by wrapping them in further compression. An HTTP GET, as you proposed, is probably the best way to go. You can use NSURLConnection and its friends for this.